# Change midlet's description in the configurations

Tags: java-me, midp, midlet

Where can I change midlet's description - the very text? Is it in some configuration file or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIDlet's description is in the Java Application Descriptor (JAD) file.

See eg [Learning Path: MIDlet Life Cycle](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/learn/midp/lifecycle/#jadsnjars) tutorial:

> The JAD file, as the name implies, *describes* a MIDlet suite. The
>   description includes the name of the MIDlet suite, the location and
>   size of the JAR file, and the configuration and profile requirements.
>   The file may also contain other *attributes*, defined by the Mobile
>   Information Device Profile (MIDP), by the developer, or both...